# How to generically read text files and save into databases without evaluating data type?

Tags: c#, database, types, pipeline

I need to write a C# program for reading any flat text files and, for every line, parses using a **regex** expression previously saved in a configuration file, which separates the line in several fields that are stored in a `List` object where each element is a field. Then, let each field be saved in the respective fields previously created within a database table and so on for each line.

At this point, everything is seen as that data is orchestrated without interference, as a pipe that runs from the text file to the database. However, I face the difficulty where some of the fields can represent dates/hours in different formats, bool, double etc. For these few cases, I will need to modify my program and make some sort of `if-statements` that would minimally generate an overhead in processing times.

The question is to know whether there is any methodology or technique within the C# that, despite the special cases mentioned, it allows me to record the data in the database without the overhead of previous evaluations to establish the data type?

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to show an example. I dont quite follow  :)

Comment: if your database table is predefined then you would already know the data types. So why can't you read from file assuming particular data type and format?

Comment: VinayC, you are right. So, let me sustain my question assuming that I do not only define the regexp expression in the config.file but also the SQL command that creates the table including the fields and types. What I really want is not to code for every text file to read and table to save. I would like something generic. Is this possible yet?

Comment: Leppie, What I want is to code a C# program that is able to read any text file and split the fields according to a format especified in a configuration file in a regexp notation, then save data it into a Database table. I do not want to code for every text file I read and save into a table. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write all of the data from the text file into a database whose fields are all strings (varchar, text, etc).  At some point you must need to query the database to use the values, and that's when you can convert from the strings into their respective data types.

Comment: Dave, thanks for your suggestion. Please let me ask you if the process of querying with conversion (may be the query can be executed more than one time) is less expensive than asking for the data type in the C# program before saving every field with the correct type into the table.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but guess is that you're better off getting the type information before saving to a database whose schema reflects the actual data types used, because querying for the information would no longer need the conversion.  If you're reading the data more than writing, then not having to do a conversion every time is probably in your best interest.  That said, I wonder if the read performance is also dependent on the ADO provider you're using.  I'm not sure.